# Flutter Firebase Auth - Your client does not have permission to get URL

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using **firebase_auth** and **google_sign_in** packages in my Flutter App. Some users are able to create an account and sign up using Google account or email and password, but some users are receiving the following error:

> [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.k: An internal error has occurred. [ Json conversion failed! Failed to parse error for string [      Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1      *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
>
> **403.** That’s an error.
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL `/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion` from this server.  That’s all we know.] ]

**Your client does not have permission to get URL. Error code: 403**

This error message is indicating that the client (my Flutter app) is being denied access to a specific URL on the Firebase server, "/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion." The error code 403, "Forbidden," is being returned from the server, which means that the server is refusing to fulfill the request, likely because the client does not have the necessary permissions.

I have checked the Firebase project's API key and OAuth client ID and they appear to be correct and valid. I have also ensured that the client is not blocked by a firewall or security group. However, I am still unable to resolve this issue and some of my users are unable to create an account and sign in.

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using cloud functions?

Comment: No, I'm not using any cloud functions, I'm just using firebase for authentication with email and password, and with google and facebook account

Answer (score 1):

**Valid only if you are using Cloud Functions**

---

I suppose you might be using Cloud Functions.

You will have to grant `Cloud Functions Invoker` role to `allusers`.

From the official documentation,

> To allow unauthenticated invocation of a function, grant the Cloud
> Functions Invoker role to the special allUsers principal on the
> function.

To read more,

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment

Complete the above mentioned step to resolve your issue.

Comment: I'm not using any cloud functions, I'm just using firebase for authentication with email and password, and with google and facebook account

Comment: It seems to be due to network https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/942